# What exactly happens when you change a file type in vim?

Tags: vim, file-type

If I have an apache file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com` and I set its filetype like so

```
:set filetype=apache
```

What does that do? Does that change the file at all? Is it only reflected in the instance of vim? The session of vim? I can manually set the filetype, but then vim warns me that I am in read only mode (`/etc/apache2` needs root access). If I open vim as root, I won't get the warning, but if I leave and open it again (as normal or root), the filetype is gone. How do I make this more permanent, at least when called from the same session file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set filetype` changes the way vim handles the file, by invoking all the `FileType` autocommands. It does not persist. If you want to always open that file with `filetype=apache`, try adding this into your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.example.com set filetype=apache
```

You can read more about it in:

```
:help 'filetype'
:help filetypes
:help :autocmd
:help .vimrc
```

**EDIT:** as found in my `/usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead access.conf*,apache.conf*,apache2.conf*,httpd.conf*,srm.conf* call s:StarSetf('apache')
au BufNewFile,BufRead */etc/apache2/*.conf*,*/etc/apache2/conf.*/*,*/etc/apache2/mods-*/*,*/etc/apache2/sites-*/*,*/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf*        call s:StarSetf('apache')
```

`s:StarSetf` will `setfiletype` to `apache` if the filetype doesn't match an ignored pattern. On my system, `:echo g:ft_ignore_pat` will show only archive file extensions as ignored. `setfiletype` does `set filetype`, but only once.

So, at least on my system, the pattern `*/etc/apache2/sites-*/*` would catch your filename and make it an `apache` file.

Comment: That seems like a pretty bad solution as it could grow unreasonably large.

Comment: vim knows how to open a number of files automagically, by using extension patterns. In particular, `*.conf` files in `/etc/apache2` are automatically assigned `filetype=apache`. You can also make an encompassing pattern for `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*`. Otherwise... well, tough.

Comment: Now that I checked, `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*` should already default to `filetype=apache`...

Answer (score 0):

The filetype basically lets Vim change settings for 'types of files'. The way it does this is by firing auto command for the FileType category when you change the filetype. This could potentially change your file if an auto command for FileType is applicable for your file (but generally plugin developers use it for r/o type changes that affect highlighting, and not the contents of the file).

If you are worried that setting the filetype is mucking with your file you can see what FileType autocommands exist by issuing the following command:

```
:au FileType
```

To setup your apache files to be apache filetypes you can put something like the following into your ~/.vimrc:

```
:au BufRead /etc/apache2/sites-available/* set ft=apache
```

Comment: I was kinda hoping the vim session file would be smart enough to save the file type.